# Is it possible to delete project files using java code?

Tags: java

My requirement is to delete  project files (class file) using java code.
The project is available in eclipse workspace and I have some condition: some  files of that project should be deleted . 
Here is a portion of my code:

```
File file2 = new File(" D:\\demoproject\\files");                      
processFile2(file2);

private static void processFile2(File file){
    System.out.println(file.delete());
    File listOfFiles[]=file.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)
    {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            if(listOfFiles[i].delete())
            {
                System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete the file");
            }
        }

        else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            processFile2(listOfFiles[i]);
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting null value in this `File listOfFiles[]=file.listFiles();`.

Comment: Isn't that because you're calling `listOfFiles[i].delete()` after deleting the parent file itself (`ystem.out.println(file.delete())`)?

Comment: What is the use case for this? It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You should never have to delete class files from within the application itself, and if you're running in a container there may not even be a filesystem in which class files reside.  Please clarify why you want to do this.

Comment: I am not sure whether it's a good idea to delete class files eclipse is generating for you. Can't this result in the project beeing out of sync or or files beeing accessed by your app and eclipse simultaneously?